# Intel Real Sense Mac OS installation

Tags: python, intel, realsense

I just got my new camera, Intel Real Sense D435i. I am using a mac, so I wanted to set up the SDK to use the camera on my computer. I  did everything as it is said in the documentation. I have had an error that it could not find CMakeLists.txt. I uploaded that file. But then when I run

`"cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DBUILD_WITH_OPENMP=false -DHWM_OVER_XU=false -G Xcode"`

it gives me this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    CMake/lrs_options.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    CMake/connectivity_check.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "OR" "OR"

  Unknown arguments specified
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know the version of CMake you were trying to use and what other steps you performed.  You say you uploaded the CMakeLists.txt file and that doesn't really make much sense.

You need to download the realsense sdk sources, create a build folder (typically in your source tree), and run your cmake line in your build folder.  That is, clone this repo https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense and then compile.  Something like this:

```
  git clone https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense.git
  cd librealsense
  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DBUILD_WITH_OPENMP=false -DHWM_OVER_XU=false
  make
```

According to the docs at https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation_osx.md you will likely also need to install a few required dependencies.